# How to incorporate a symmetrical padValue with focal function in raster

Tags: r, matrix, r-raster

I have a raster matrix with non-negative values (each pixel has a height value), and would like to calculate some custom height metrics with a 5x5 moving window, using symmetrical padding around the edges of the matrix .

I had done some basic calculations using pktools (spatial filter) in QGIS (mean, standard deviation, maximum), which allowed me to do this (padding using zeros, replicates or symmetrical).

Now that I want to calculate some other metrics using custom functions (i.e. coefficient of heights, skewness and kurtosis), I cannot use pktools. I have been trying to use the `focal()` function in `raster`, but the padValue needs to be numeric. Is there a way around this, so I can have symmetrical borders? I tried the following:

```
> f.CoH <- function(x) {sd(x)/mean(x)}
> 
> CoH <- focal(raster, w=matrix(1,nrow=5,ncol=5), fun=f.CoH, pad=TRUE,
> padValue="symmetric")
```

But get the following error:

```
> Warning message: In .local(x, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `padValue = NA`.

You'd also need to modify the function to deal with NAs:

```
f.CoH <- function(x) {sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)}
```

Consider however that this would give somewhat different results wrt "symmetrical padding", because the standard deviation and average obtained by padding with NAs and by replicating values would be different.

HTH

Comment: Is there a way to replicate the values instead then? I would prefer this than NAs or 0's.

Comment: Not that I know of, unless you want to program it. However, in my opinion filling with NAs is better than replicating: at least, the statistics you derive are based on real data, while replicating data introduces fake data and treats it as if it were real.